# MySQL query to select rows from table 2 if *all* rows from table 1 are not present

Tags: mysql, join

I'm doing a kind of point-of-sale system whose MySQL database has (among other things) a table with items for sale, a table with sales, and a table with purchases (a purchase being my ad-hoc notation for any single item bought in a sale; if the same person buys three items at once, for example, that's one sale consisting of three purchases). All these tables have logical IDs, viz. `item_id`, `sale_id`, `purchase_id`, and are easily joined with simple pivotal tables.

I am now trying to add a discount feature; basically your garden-variety supermarket discount: buy these particular items and pay X instead of paying the full sum of the regular item prices. These 'package deals' have their own table and are linked to the `items` table with a simple pivotal table containing `deal_id` and `item_id`.

My problem is getting to the point of figuring out when this is to be applied. To give some example data:

```
items
+---------+--------+---------+
| item_id | title  | price   |
+---------+--------+---------+
|      12 | Shoe   |      10 |
|      76 | Coat   |      23 |
|      82 | Whip   |      19 |
+---------+--------+---------+

sales
+---------+-----------+
| sale_id | timestamp |
+---------+-----------+
|    2973 | 144995839 |
|    3092 | 144996173 |
+---------+-----------+

purchases
+-------------+-------------+---------+----------+---------+
| purchase_id | no_of_items | item_id | at_price | sale_id |
+-------------+-------------+---------+----------+---------+
|       12993 |           1 |      12 |       10 |    2973 |
|       12994 |           1 |      76 |       23 |    2973 |
|       12996 |           1 |      82 |       19 |    2973 |
|       13053 |           1 |      12 |       10 |    3092 |
|       13054 |           1 |      82 |       19 |    3092 |
+-------------+-------------+---------+----------+---------+

package_deals
+---------+-------+
| deal_id | price |
+---------+-------+
|       1 |    40 |
+---------+-------+

deals_items
+---------+---------+
| deal_id | item_id |
+---------+---------+
|       1 |      12 |
|       1 |      76 |
|       1 |      82 |
+---------+---------+
```

As is hopefully obvious from that, we have a shoe that cost $10 (let's just assume we use dollars as our currency here, doesn't matter), a coat that costs $23, and a whip that costs $19. We also have a package deal that if you buy both a shoe, a coat, and a whip, you get the whole thing for $40 altogether.

Of the two sales given, one (2973) has purchased all three things and will get the discount, while the other (3092) has purchased only the shoe and the whip and won't get the discount.

In order to find out whether or not to apply the package-deal discount, I of course have to find out whether **all** the `item_id`s in a package deal are present in the `purchases` table for a given `sale_id`.

**How do I do this?**

I thought I should be able to do something like this:

```
SELECT     deal_id, item_id, purchase_id
FROM       package_deals
LEFT JOIN  deals_items
    USING  (deal_id)
LEFT JOIN  purchases
    USING  (item_id)
WHERE
    sale_id = 2973
AND item_id IS NULL
GROUP BY   deal_id
```

In my head, that retrieved all rows from the `package_deal` table where at least one of the `item_id`s associated with the package deal in question does not have a corresponding match in the `purchases` table for the `sale_id` given. This would then have told me which packages *don't* apply; i.e., it would return zero rows for purchase 2973 (since none of the items associated with package deal 1 are absent from the `purchases` table filtered on `sale_id = 2973`) and one row for 3092 (since one of the items associated with package deal one—namely the coat, `item_id` 76—is absent from the `purchases` table filtered on `sale_id = 3092`).

Obviously, it doesn't do what I naïvely thought it would—rather, it just always returns zero rows, no matter what.

It doesn't really matter much to me whether the resulting set gives me one row for each package deal that *should* apply, or one for each package deal that *shouldn't* apply—but **how do I get it to show me either in a single query?**

Is it even possible?

Comment: you use `LEFT JOIN  deals_items` in query, but didn't provide any sample of this table

Comment: @Alex Eh? `deals_items` is the last in the sample tables…

Comment: Ah... ok... have to scrolll... sorry :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your query above is that `sale_id` is also NULL in the missing row that you're interested in, due to the LEFT JOIN.

This query will return the `deal_id` for any deals that DO NOT apply to a given order:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
            pd.deal_id
FROM        package_deals pd
JOIN        deals_items di on pd.deal_id = di.deal_id
WHERE       di.item_id NOT IN (SELECT item_id FROM purchases WHERE sale_id = 3092)
```

From that it's easy to work out the ones that do apply. Note that for a fully functioning system, you'd still need to take the purchase quantities into account - e.g. if the customer had bought 2 of two the items in the deal, but only 1 of the third... etc.

A SQL fiddle demonstrating the query is here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f2ae4/8

Note that I've made my joins using the `ON` syntax, as I'm simply more familiar than with `USING`. I expect that would work too if you prefer it.

Comment: Oh! Of course it is. `sale_id` is in the table I’m trying to check for empty values. D’oh! What a brain fart. Thank you for unfogging my brain for me! I never realised you could use `IN` like this, either—very useful. (I swear some day I’m going to sit down and properly learn SQL, proper-like.)